# run custom shell script 'Run Script' error while archiving the project

Tags: ios

I have stucked in a problem that when I run app it runs fine but when I try to create .ipa file there is compiling issue and error thrown **"run custom shell script 'Run Script' "**.There are four targets in My App.I tried lots of solutions to get out from it but nothing works.please if anyone could let me know the exact solution.Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: For each target, click on the target, choose "Build Phases". Go through your scripts and comment out them (or rename them) to see which one is failing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply,I try to do this.

Comment: Let me know you one thing,except one target,all the target are being archived successfully.Only one target which when archived then there is error.

Comment: Ok what scripts do you have in that target? Under 'Build Phases'.

Comment: There are two Run Scripts one for Fabric Framework,another for GoogleService.Other than these,Copy Pods Resources,Embed pods Frameworks etc.

Comment: Does any of them have the name "Run Script"?

Comment: Yes,actually both scripts name are the same which is Run Script and same in remaining targets.

Comment: Rename them by clicking on the title twice and then build again. Then you'll probably which one is failing. Then comment out the script that is failing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109549/discussion-between-akshay-hastekar-and-mikael).

Comment: Thanks man,It shows me the script which was causing error,I commented that script also unchecked the two boxes,but still giving error for the same script.do I need to remove that?

Answer (score -2):

This might be help you:

Please make sure that internet is connected while archiving the project